# What is the "DIR" in wpa_supplicant.conf file?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

To connect a linux machine to a wifi hotspot automatically through command line interface, it is needed to configure the file located at `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

While looking at the file, the line below is noticed:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
```

I am wondering to understand what is the DIR in it and why it is used.

Many thanks.

Comment: Directory it seems

Comment: It is the requirement to connect to wifi.

What if there was no 'DIR=' ?
@PRATAP